# Are Grassmannians toric varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties, grassmannians

Are Grassmannians $G(k,n)$ toric varieties for all possible $k,n$? If they are toric varieties, are there any descriptions for the fans?

Comment: Look at page 5 of http://math.mit.edu/~mckernan/Teaching/10-11/Spring/18.726/l_4.pdf for a negative answer to your first question. BTW: This was proof by Google. It is best to Google first and ask MO questions later!

Comment: The Grassmannian $G(k,n)$ is toric if and only if $k = 1$ or $k = n - 1$, in which case it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$.  Instead of having a dense orbit for a torus in general, it always has a dense orbit for a Borel subgroup of $SL(n)$ (e.g. the subgroup of upper triangular matrices of determinant 1).

Comment: I did not know this.

Comment: @Jon Bannon Thank you! But why "the toric variety in $\mathbb{P}^5$ must be defined by a binomial" as commented in the article you cited.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You are welcome, Li Yutong. I honestly could not have answered your question, since I know absolutely nothing about toric varieties. I only posted what I did because it was easy to find on Google...and if it was easy for me to find, then it is easy for anyone to find. Good luck!